# Ошибка "таймаут семафора" телеграм бот aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, aiohttp

Столкнулся с ошибкой, которая не даёт моему боту работать стабильно. Любая работа с медиа файлами и inline клавиатурами может приводить к данной ошибке:

```py
raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: 
{e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientOSError: 
[WinError 121] Превышен таймаут семафора
```

Если ошибка возникает, то бот не отвечает на запросы пользователя, хотя функции работают, но через раз...

Например у меня есть функция отправки сообщения с inline клавиатурой:

```py
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "Главное меню" or message.text == "Назад")
async def main_menu(message: types.Message):
    """Главное меню"""
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    if chat_id in out_state:
        del out_state[chat_id]
    if chat_id in out_info:
        del out_info[chat_id]
    await bot.send_message(chat_id, texts.main_menu, reply_markup=main_keyboard(), parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    if chat_id in BotDB.get_all_admin_user_ids():
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, texts.adminCommands, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
```

И также сама inline клавиатура:

```py
def main_keyboard():
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    click_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("⚡️Клик", callback_data="click")
    curs_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Курс", callback_data="curs")
    vallet_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Кошелёк", callback_data="vallet")
    ref_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Рефералы", callback_data="ref")
    change_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Обмен", callback_data="change")
    out_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Списать коины", callback_data="out")
    ads_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Реклама", callback_data="soon")
    work_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("✨Задания", callback_data="soon")
    info_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ℹИнформация", callback_data="info")
    keyboard.add(click_button, curs_button, vallet_button, ref_button, change_button, out_button, ads_button, work_button, info_button)
    return keyboard
```

При попытке вызвать данное меню бот может зависнуть и выдать ошибку семафора или наоборот моментально ответить.

Пытался сам понять в чем проблема, но так решения не нашёл. Возможно если запустить на сервере проблема исчезнет, но у меня нет возможности это проверить.

Сталкивался ли кто-то с данной проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю Вы уже прошерстили весь рунет в поисках ответа, но нашли только догадки так вот...

Как я решил эту проблему - погнал траффик своего серва через арендованный сервер вне РФ, и о чудо, трабл исчез.

Вы можете просто поставить vpn, или пустить трафик python через прокси.

В чем же проблема?
**Вопрос к провайдеру...**

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент у многих происходят проблемы с телеграмом, например:

**Бот изменяет сообщение с задержкой**

**Определённые команды в какой - либо момент просто перестают доходить до бота**

**У некоторых телеграм не работает без VPN.**

Есть несколько вариантов решения:

1. Попробовать использовать VPN
2. Попробовать запустить бота на хостинг-сервере, из бесплатных (не реклама, но сам проверял):
   2.1 Serv00.com (лучше попробовать первым, т.к. ограничены места)

   2.2 Pythonanywhere

   2.3 Google shell

   2.4 Google Collab

   2.5 Сайт для запуска python кода и возможностью установки библиотек

   2.6 Онлайн виртуалки (onworks например, но pip прийдется ставить через get-pip)

   2.7 Онлайн эмуляторы UNIX терминала
3. Проверить скорость интернета
4. Сменить библиотеку (предкрайний случай)
5. (Уже крайний случай) Сменить провайдера

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендации, я запустил бота на платном vps сервере и задержки стали в разы реже и все сообщения стали доходить, но до сих пор время от времени что-то тормозит. Действительно, сильно зависит стабильность работы от сервера…

Comment: @Timonous не за что, скорее всего всё-таки у телеграма проблемы